# VBA Out of Memory and crashing

Tags: excel, vba, memory

I have created a worksheet_change event and I have found that the code crashes from running out of memory. I have found that the code runs out of memory at the For each Cell in SheetRange section and displays  at the Watch List. I have messed around with the Application.EnableEvents and removing the extra loop (the counter), but neither of these prevent the code from crashing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim modifier As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer, R As Variant
Dim counter As Integer, SheetAddress As Worksheet, SheetName As String, SheetRange As Range, cell As Range
Dim startRng As Variant, EndRng As Variant, Brng As Range, t As Variant
'_____________________________________|PART 1 - In $ AMOUNT|________________________________________________
Set modifier = Range("E4:U29")

If Not Intersect(Target, modifier) Is Nothing Then
    counter = 1
    Do While counter <= 2
        For i = 4 To 28
            For j = 6 To 21
                'On Error Resume Next
                Dim rowcount As Variant
                SheetName = CStr(Cells(i, j).End(xlUp))
                Set SheetAddress = Sheets(SheetName)
                rowcount = SheetAddress.Range(SheetAddress.Cells(6, 2), SheetAddress.Cells(6, 2).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
                For t = 4 To rowcount
                    If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) >= 27 And SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                        If IsEmpty(startRng) Then
                            startRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                        End If
                    End If
                    If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                        EndRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                    End If
                Next t
                        
                Set SheetRange = SheetAddress.Range(startRng, EndRng)
                Dim offsetstart As Variant, offsetend As Variant
                offsetstart = SheetAddress.Range(startRng).Offset(0, 9)
                offsetend = SheetAddress.Range(EndRng).Offset(0, 9)
                
                'formula
                For Each cell In SheetRange
                    If cell.Value = Cells(i, "A") Then
                        Cells(i, j) = cell.Offset(0, 9) * Cells(i, "E")
                    End If
                Next cell
            Next j
        Next i
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
End If

'column totals
For j = 6 To 21
    Cells(29, j) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(29, j).Offset(-25), Cells(29, j).Offset(-1)))
Next j

'grand total
Cells(29, "V") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("F29:U29"))
With Cells(29, "V")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End With


'_____________________________________|PART 2 - In UNITS (Hours)|___________________________________________
Dim startcell As Integer, endcell As Integer, Brange As Range
Set modifier = Range("E33:U58")

If Not Intersect(Target, modifier) Is Nothing Then
    counter = 1
    Do While counter <= 2
        For i = 33 To 57
            For j = 6 To 21
                On Error Resume Next
                SheetName = CStr(Cells(i, j).End(xlUp))
                Set SheetAddress = Sheets(SheetName)
                rowcount = SheetAddress.Range(SheetAddress.Cells(4, 2), SheetAddress.Cells(4, 2).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
                For t = 4 To rowcount
                    If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) >= 27 And SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                        If IsEmpty(startRng) Then
                            startRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                        End If
                    End If
                    If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                        EndRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                    End If
                Next t
                        
                Set SheetRange = SheetAddress.Range(startRng, EndRng)
                offsetstart = SheetAddress.Range(startRng).Offset(0, 9)
                offsetend = SheetAddress.Range(EndRng).Offset(0, 9)
                'formula
                For Each cell In SheetRange
                    If cell.Value = Cells(i, "A") Then
                        Cells(i, j) = cell.Offset(0, 8) * Cells(i, "E")
                    End If
                Next cell
            Next j
        Next i
    counter = counter + 1
    Loop
End If

Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(1, 21)).EntireColumn.AutoFit

'column Totals
For j = 6 To 21
    Cells(58, j) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(58, j).Offset(-25), Cells(58, j).Offset(-1)))
Next j

'grand Total
Cells(58, "V") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("F58:U58"))
With Cells(58, "V")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End With



Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add detailed descriptions of what each part of the code is supposed to do. Also, add screenshots of your data and provide some sample data as text so we can test your procedure. Why are the codes below the *If* statements outside the *If* statements? Should they really run if no 'adequate' change was detected?

Comment: Try adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning of your code.  Then add `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of it.

Comment: ...because every time your code updates the sheet, the `change` event is triggered again

Comment: This statement looks suspect `rowcount = SheetAddress.Range(SheetAddress.Cells(6, 2), SheetAddress.Cells(6, 2).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`   ...   because `rowcount` may be much larger than you think and this may be causing the out of memory error.

Comment: Documentation is critical.  Much of your code is confusing.  For example, why would you set `startRng` in every loop in `For t = 4 To rowcount` (so, up to 2 million+ times?), then use only the last value?  Then  in `For Each cell In SheetRange` you could be calling this recursively because you are firing `Worksheet_Change` each time you update `Cells(i, j)`.  But that depends on what your `if` statements are intended to do.